# JasperReports: Exporting report using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I am trying to download a *JasperReports* report from my local machine using *Spring MVC* and *AngularJS* in Zip Format.  I have taken cue from a JSF code and tried to replicate it in *Spring*. But `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` is returning `null` and thats where the code blows up. I would like some help, maybe a substitute for this `FacesContext` or some other advice for which I would be really thankful.

My Service Handler:

```
public SubmissionReportDto excelDownload(Map<String, String> contractData) throws IOException {
    String contractId = contractData.get(DBConstants.PROC_PI_CONTRACT_ID);
    String versionNo = contractData.get(DBConstants.VERSION_NO);

    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    String zipFileName = "";
    String fileName = "";

    submissionReportJasperDao = new SubmissionReportJasperDaoImpl();

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    try {
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;
        submissionReportDto.setReportName("Billing Related Parameters.jasper");
        String reportName = submissionReportDto.getReportName();

        byte[] buffer = submissionReportJasperDao.mainReportXLS(contractId, versionNo, reportName);
        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
        response.setHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
        response.setContentType("application/xls");
        response.setContentType("application/zip");

        try {
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        zos.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
        zos.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        try {
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            zos.write(buffer);
            zos.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Exception" + e);

    } finally {
        if (null != zos) {
            zos.flush();
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();
        }
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete();
    submissionReportDto.setSuccessMessage("Download Success");
    return submissionReportDto;
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted any of your configuration, but `FacesContext` is a context for Java Server **Faces**. If you're no longer using JSF, there really is no context for it, and you need to use the Spring equivalents. In this particular case, a whole lot of what you are doing can be done implicitly with Spring annotations and general view-mapping magic.

Comment: Yeah,I am not using JSF. Can I in any way configure to use FacesContext??

Comment: Or can you elaborate me with any view-mapping magic

Comment: No, because that's a part of JSF. You wouldn't try to use a Spring `ApplicationContext` in a JSF-only application.

Comment: *Why* are you wanting to switch to Spring MVC if this is working? The Spring MVC approach to handling this sort of request is almost completely different and would need essentially a complete rewrite.

Comment: Actually this I wrote in some other application,but with this new one I have to use Spring.Kind of a no choice situation.

Comment: Thought might just work,with some little modifications,obviously.